# angular.js ng-repeat + infinite scroll causing too many watchers

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have this code:

```
<section infinite-scroll='load()'>
    <div class="product" ng-repeat="product in products | limitTo:total">
        ..
    </div>
 </section>
```

In controller:

```
$scope.products = []; // array of all products
$scope.load = function() {
   $scope.total += 5;
};
```

When an user scrolls to the bottom controller increases limitTo variable so he would see 5 more products. If there are **40 products** site has **4700 watchers**. If he keeps scrolling there might be even 12k watchers.. Any ideas how to fix that? Each product has various inputs for adding to cart action.

I was taking a look for virtual repeat(e.g. [this](https://material.angularjs.org/HEAD/#/demo/material.components.virtualRepeat)), but it's using a container with fixed height so it would be ugly and completely wrong to scroll products like that.

Comment: try using **track by** https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngRepeat

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Angular will place a watch on every binding expression that you have. You'll have to reduce the number of binding expressions in your code to see a decrease in the number of watches.

However you can try to alleviate the problem by using **track by** to help angular figure out what shouldn't be re-evaluated.

```html
<section infinite-scroll='load()'>
    <div class="product" ng-repeat="product in products | limitTo:total track by $index">
        ..
    </div>
 </section>
```

In order to remove unneeded watches consider rendering only what is visible to the user and replacing everything else with empty elements if possible.

Comment: @dontHaveName I forgot to mention track by in my answer: It is usually a given when working with huge lists. So definitely try this answer.

Comment: we had similar issues and used windowing with great success. :)

Comment: when I use track by it looks like it's going threw whole list of products so it's causing a few seconds to load the page

Comment: that might be because of the **$index**, if your products have some unique id try using that instead.

Comment: can you try seeing what takes so long? do some profiling in the browser maybe?

Comment: I solved it with adding ng-if="quickAction==product.id"(because form is hiding and showing when you click at button) on each product's form so now it has up to 1000 watchers instead of 15000

Answer (score 1):

You don't say whether the list is supposed to be editable or not. That said, I don't think a *monster* list (thousands of elements) editable is feasible anyway.

In a project I'm working on we have the same use case as the one you present. So far, with about 5000 elements in the list, it seems to be working great: We have gone to great lengths to use [one-time binding](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/expression)s and create efficient directories which frees up their watchers as quickly as possible.

For editing we pass on the element which is clicked on and open that in a separate context.

Comment: actually I'm using one-time binding but I don't know looks like it's not working/helping.